# Amazon Ec2 instance -Public DNS is detected as trojan

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2

I am running Amazon linux Micro instance.I have configured php,apache and phantomjs in the instance.

When i first accessed the server from a browser 'Avast' antivirus threw me a popup that this site has trojan.

Please help me out.

Comment: Check your html for "<script>" tags that shouldn't be there.

Comment: there were no <script> tags in the index.html or any other html pages in the server

Comment: Are you using addons in your browser?

Comment: No.I tried in systems. Mcafee also detects the same. "dsparking.com" trojan etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy fix.  Don't host trojans from an Amazon EC2 instance; [RBN is much better for that sort of thing anyway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Business_Network).

Assuming you aren't actually serving up malware from your site, this can be caused by the use of a database of bad IPs Avast is using that's just not up to date - the last guy at the IP you were assigned may have been serving up malware.

Check your site with other AV vendors, and if it's actually clean, wait and/or contact Avast to get your IP off their bad IP list.

Comment: It makes sense.I associated a new ipaddress for my instance and now the antiviruses were not blocking it. Thanks.

Comment: Thought i am not actually hosting malware :-)